# nicematrix: align first line of a mono-cell block to the baseline

Tags: nicematrix

I want the words "First" and "Second" to have the same baseline.
I found a solution with raisebox but is there a better solution?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

First \begin{NiceTabular}[t]{c}[hvlines]
\Block{}{Second \\ $ \frac{1}{2} $} \\
1 \\
2 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: SebGlav, user238301, F. Pantigny thank you for your answers, I accept them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added in the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 5.14 2021-04-08) a key `t` for the command `\Block`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

First \begin{NiceTabular}[t]{c}[hvlines]
\Block[t]{}{Second \\ $ \frac{1}{2} $} \\
1 \\
2 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: This solution is perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

Why not including it into your `NiceTabular`?

[image: align in nicematrix]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

    \begin{NiceTabular}{cc}[hvlines-except-corners]
        \Block[draw=white]{}{First \\ \vphantom{$ \frac{1}{2} $}}  & \Block[draw]{}{Second \\ $ \frac{1}{2} $} \\
        & 1 \\
         & 2 \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

Another solution I found (if you really want to place your tabular right  after plain text) is to avoid using `\Block` for the first line, draw only vlines, then add all hlines in `\CodeAfter`. The result is not exactly the same and imho, is less correct.

```
First   \begin{NiceTabular}{c}[vlines,baseline=t]
        Second \\
        $ \frac{1}{2} $ \\
        1 \\
        2 \\
        \CodeAfter \tikz \draw (1) -- (1-|2) (1|-3) -- (3) (1|-4) -- (4) (1|-5) -- (5);
    \end{NiceTabular}
```

[image: v2]

Comment: Remark: In your second solution, you could have drawn the horizontal rules with `\hline` as in `{tabular}`...

Comment: Of course, you're totally right, François. Seems that I got carried away with `\AfterCode`.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you don't need a mono-cell `\Block` but only a `\Blok{2-1}{}` in the first cell in order to be able to use the key `hvlines` with the output you expect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

First \begin{NiceTabular}[t]{c}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=1pt]
\Block{2-1}{}%
Second \\ 
$\frac{1}{2}$\\
1 \\
2 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: That was so simple!

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround is to replace the `\Block` by a `t`-aligned tabular. To me it seems that it could be a valid feature request for `nicematrix` to add a `t` option for `\Block` (unless it is already there).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

First \begin{NiceTabular}[t]{c}[hvlines]
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
Second \\ $ \frac{1}{2} $\\[0.2ex]
\end{tabular} \\
1 \\
2 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have followed your suggestion to add a key `t` for the command `\Block` (added in v. 5.14). See my new answer for that question.